# Nuxt3 application: how to host the api part?

Tags: deployment, nuxt3

I am new to nuxt and node technologies. I have an app that in addition to a vuejs frontend also uses an api backend to access a database.

It seems to me I understand how to generate the front end with

```
npx nuxi generate
```

and then upload the .output.public folder  to a static domain.

But what to do with the api part that is located under the server directory?

At the moment I have only an embryo that is like this

```
server

    api
        person.get.ts
        person.post.ts
        person.put.ts
        person.delete.ts  
    routes
        (empty folder)
```

All this runs perfectly in the development environment.

In my hosting there is a cpanel with a node.js setup tool that requires the following information:
[image]

**Application mode:** dev or prod (this I understand)

**Application root:** the place where to upload my application files
This I am not sure to perfectly understand.
Should I upload here the content of the above server folder **as is** or should I run a npm command to prepare the stuff?

**Application URL:** the http/https link to the application
I understand where the domain points Probably needs an htaccess file.

**Application startup file:**
I cannot see what it is . The guide of the hosting gives server.js as example but I have no server.js file not even any .js file under the server directory

I hope I am clear enough to receive ad hoc help? Thank you in advance.

PS: I do not want to change of hosting provider thus please don't suggest me other hosting solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npm run build` which will generate `.output` directory in your project folder. Then you take contents of this folder and upload them.

```
.output\
  - public\
  - server\
  - nitro.json
```

Application startup file should be `server\index.mjs`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that I understand but at the moment I have trouble with my ftp connection and I cannot verify. In fact as I had to use the a nuxt generate command to have my frontend static and prerenderd I didn't have a .output/server dir. Now I understand I have to proceed in 2 stages first generate for front end. Then build for backend. Therefore, it would have been more practical to develop the 2 parts separately. Isn't it?

Comment: If you run `nuxt generate` you'll create static (SSG) build without runtime server (Nitro), just standalone JavaScript. You won't need Node.js to run it, only the browser, but it will have limited functionality (like no `/server` part) . Might be enough, depending on your application needs. Command `nuxt build` creates fully functional Nuxt app fully powered by Nitro, which on the other hand needs Node.js (or alternative JS runtime).